# I am not able to make migrations to the following file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, web-deployment

I am trying to create the **migration** of the following models.py code but the following error is occuring ???(I am learning Web-Devlopment from [CS50-Web Devlopment Courese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzP164YANAU&list=PLhQjrBD2T380xvFSUmToMMzERZ3qB5Ueu&index=11))
Can Anyone help me solve the error is I have very little knowledge about django, sqlite and as well as Web-devlopment.

```
    from django.db import models
    class Flight(models.Model):
        origin = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        destination = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        duration = models.IntegerField()
```

---

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Books\Programming\Web Devlopment\Lecture-4\airline\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Books\Programming\Web Devlopment\Lecture-4\airline\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 455, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Books\Programming\Web Devlopment\Lecture-4\airline\airline\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('flights/', include('flights.urls') ),
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementInclude.py", line 128, in include
    _include(elem, loader, base_url, max_depth, set())
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementInclude.py", line 136, in _include
    if e.tag == XINCLUDE_INCLUDE:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

Comment: Remove `,`  at the end of your field declaration

Comment: I removed the "," but still the same Attribute error is showing . That 'str' object has no attribute 'tag'

Comment: [edit] your question and provide error

Comment: I have edited the code please help me solve that

Comment: Somewhere in your code you're trying to check this this condistion `if e.tag == XINCLUDE_INCLUDE:` and this line is raising error.

Comment: i searched the 'if e.tag == XINCLUDE_INCLUDE:' but their was no such thing in my code

Comment: Error is on this line in your url file: `path('flights/', include('flights.urls') ),`. I don't know why. You need to share your `airline\urls.py` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing `include` from wrong module.Probably from `xml.etree.ElementInclude`

So change

```
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
```

to

```
from django.urls import include
```

in your `airline/urls.py` file.